# c# wcf file and folder browser

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, filesystems, file-permissions

I have a windows service that host a wcf service to allow remot file and folder browsing. The windows service runs under the local system account.

When browsing the `c:\` drive the service reports over 2800 files in that folder.
i have single stepped through the code and it does indeed report >2800 files.

How can this be correct?

**C# Code**

```
   //Files Manager

public ReturnClass FindSubFiles(String Folder_To_Search, String User, String SessionId)
{
    ReturnClass myReturnClass = new ReturnClass(-1, String.Empty, String.Empty, null, null, null, null);
    try
    {
        Logging.Write_To_Log_File("Entry", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, "", "", "", "", User, SessionId, 1);
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Folder_To_Search);
        int count = 0;
        foreach (string Folder in filePaths)
        {
            filePaths[count] = Path.GetFileName(filePaths[count]);

            count++;
        }
        myReturnClass.ErrorCode = 1;
        myReturnClass.FilePaths = filePaths;
        Logging.Write_To_Log_File("Exit", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, "", "", "", "", User, SessionId, 1);
        return myReturnClass;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        Logging.Write_To_Log_File("Error", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, "", "", ex.ToString(), "", User, SessionId, 2);
        myReturnClass.ErrorCode = -1;
        myReturnClass.ErrorMessage = ex.ToString();
        return myReturnClass;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you taken into account for hidden files or system files if any..?

Comment: yes but when i view hidden files there is only about 30 files or so. remember the service is running under the local system account which may see other files that even admins cant see - im not sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the path i was passing in was c:
what i should be passing in is c:\\

**C# Code**

```
public ReturnClass FindSubFiles(String Folder_To_Search , 
                                String User, String SessionId )
{
    ReturnClass myReturnClass = new ReturnClass(-1, String.Empty, String.Empty, 
                                               null, null, null, null);
    try
    {
        Logging.Write_To_Log_File("Entry", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, 
                                  "", "", "", "", User, SessionId, 1);
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Folder_To_Search + "\\");
        int count = 0;
        foreach (string Folder in filePaths)
        {
            filePaths[count] = Path.GetFileName(filePaths[count]);

            count++;
        }
        myReturnClass.ErrorCode = 1;
        myReturnClass.FilePaths = filePaths;
        Logging.Write_To_Log_File("Exit", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, 
                                  "", "", "", "", User, SessionId, 1);
        return myReturnClass;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        Logging.Write_To_Log_File("Error", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, 
                                  "", "", ex.ToString(), "", User, SessionId, 2);
        myReturnClass.ErrorCode = -1;
        myReturnClass.ErrorMessage = ex.ToString();
        return myReturnClass;
    }
}
```

thanks
Damo

Answer (score 1):

Paste this into a C# Console Application and see what it spits out.  You must be passing in something unexpected in your folder_To_Search, or have more files than you think in c:\

```
var Folder_To_Search = @"c:\";
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Folder_To_Search);
int count = 0;
foreach (string Folder in filePaths)
{
    filePaths[count] = Path.GetFileName(filePaths[count]);

    count++;
}
Console.WriteLine(count);
Console.ReadKey();
```